# Do I need to create database scheme before I start with data ingestion?

Tags: apache-kafka, graph-databases, memgraphdb

I want to ingest data from Kafka data stream right into Memgraph. Do I need to define the types of data before I start the data ingestion?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, there is no need to explicitly define the data types before starting the ingestion process.